# Loading parts of a struct into a another struct

Tags: c, struct

I want to load a struct with 3 values into a struct with only 2 values.

```
typedef struct {
     double x;
     double y;
     } twod;

typedef struct {
     double x;
     double y;
     double z;
    } threed;
```

The 2nd struct contains arrays of coordinates for the 3d plane. The goal is to just load the `x` and `y` coordinates into the 1st struct from the 2nd struct.

Is that possible considering they are different typedefs? How would a solution be implemented?

Answer (score 1):

No, of course it's not directly possible since it won't fit.

But you can copy the fields manually, of course:

```
twod atwod;
threed athreed;

athreed.x = 1.0;
athreed.y = 2.0;
athreed.z = 3.0;

atwod.x = athreed.x;
atwod.y = athreed.y;
```

You can make scary assumptions and use `memcpy()` but it won't be worth it.

Of course, you can also go all inheritance-based and re-structure `threed`:

```
typedef struct {
  twod xy;
  double z;
} threed;
```

Then you can do:

```
atwod = athree3.xy;
```

But accesses to `threed` become less clear.

Comment: What would happen if instead I had a array that stored threed structs? How would I get twod to store all the variables?                          eg: [ (x1,y1,z1), (x2,y2,z2), (x3,y3,z3) ] ->                             [ (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3)]

Comment: Good idea. You can use a union type to make access for x and y possible in threed. - I posted it as own awnser if you don't mind.

Comment: @Pyrons Whether or not you have an array doesn't matter, you still have to copy for each element.

Answer (score 0):

You'd do it simply with the = operator:

```
threed a = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
twod   b;

b.x = a.x;
b.y = a.y;
```

Answer (score 0):

Continuing unwinds idea:

```
typedef struct {
  double x; 
  double y;
} twod;

typedef struct {
  union {
    struct {
      double x;
      double y;
    };
    twod xy;
  };
  double z;
} threed;
```

Sample programm:

```
int main() {
  threed vec = {1, 2, 3};
  vec.y = 5;
  twod v2 = vec.xy;
  printf("x:%g y:%g z:%g\n", v2.x, v2.y, vec.z);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe this should work...

```
threed from;
from.x = 10;
from.y = 20;
from.z = 30;

twod to;

memcpy(&to, &from, sizeof(double) * 2);
```

Comment: I'd say doing it this way is not a good idea! Use the = operator as in the other examples.

Comment: I was assuming he was asking for some different alternative since the = operator method is blatantly obvious.